How to clear out the asset libray entirely
How do i clear out the asset library, I know i can go to Edit > preferences and turn off the selected library but when i add another its gonna keep the categories and the files assigned to those. is there a way to clear all of that data without going into every single Blend file and clearing out their asset data?
